# I added an image that for some reason adds a scroll bar. I also have an issue with a text element

Tags: html, css, image, text, alignment

Issue 1/2: 
I added an image that switches between some other images and it added a scroll bar to the right even though there is no content to the right of the page. I can't seem to get rid of the scroll bar. Refer to image 1 and 2.

Issue 2/2: The text doesn't stay in the center of the image when I make my browser smaller. Refer to image 3.

The code: I wanted to paste the code here but it kept giving indent errors so you can view the page at www.mh-rp.com and you can see the relevant code there in the main tags and the .centered in the css part.

Images:
`[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Wq8.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89BdD.jpg)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8nq9.png%60)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this code in your css file

```
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Here is the solution for your second problem

```
 .image_container{
   position:relative;
 }
```

Since your text is position absolute, you need to make the parent position relative. This will make sure the child is positioned absolutely in relation to the parent container.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much. That resolved the first issue. Do you also know the solution to the text issue shown in image 3?

Comment: No problem, Sean. Let me know if the second code worked out for you.

Comment: Hey Henry, thanks a lot for the explanation as well. It fixed the issue and I now understand more about how it works!!